# codeigniter translate_uri_dashes doesn't work

Tags: php, url-rewriting, codeigniter-3

I can't resolve this myself...

in CI 3, route.php:

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = true;
$route['why-croatia'] = 'why_croatia';
```

Everything works fine on my local WAMP, but after moving to production server, pages which contain dash in URI (why-croatia) for example are returned with 404 Page Not Found.

```
In CI log it says:
DEBUG - 2017-05-17 23:01:50 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2017-05-17 23:01:50 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
ERROR - 2017-05-17 23:01:50 --> 404 Page Not Found: Why_croatia/index
```

Why big first letter W?

Same problem on other server with nginx?! Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try first with index.php in URL to see if response can be given. Also, try without route set. You can avoid `$route['why-croatia'] = 'why_croatia';` since `$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = true;` this is set to true.

Comment: @Tpojka If I remove `$route['why-croatia'] = 'why_croatia';` then it doesn't work. It seems that `$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = true;` has no impact ?!

Comment: Thing is it should actually. Clear your browser cache and try again. You can try it in private browsing window to be sure there would be no cache issue.

Comment: Turned out, that at the end of the routing rules in routes.php, there's default rule added by CI, $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE, which I didn't saw at first. That rule was overwriting same rule added by me  at the beginning. My mistake, but maybe this will help to someone. :)